# Issue trying to save model with tensorflow.keras.models.save_model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-science

I have a character level CNN model below.  I am able to save in H5 format, but I need to deploy the model in saved model bundle format.  Code below:

```html
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix
import tensorflow.python.keras.saving.saved_model
# Preprocessing
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

# Modeling
import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, Dropout, MaxPooling1D, Conv1D, GlobalMaxPool1D, Bidirectional, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Lambda, Bidirectional, concatenate, BatchNormalization, Embedding
from tensorflow.keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend as K

import IPython
from IPython.display import SVG
from tensorflow.keras.utils import model_to_dot

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

save_path = "saved_path"



def get_raw_data():
    # Get file
    df = pd.read_csv(
        "data_path",
        sep=',',
        names=['raw command', 'label']
    )

    df.dropna(0, subset=["raw command"], inplace=True)

    # label
    return df[['label', 'raw command']]

df = get_raw_data()
df.head()

print('Number of data points: %d' % (len(df)))

train_df, test_df = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.3)


class CharCNN:

    CHAR_DICT = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 .!?:,\'%-\(\)/$+{}`~=_|&;[]^@#&*"'

    def __init__(self, max_len_of_sentence, max_num_of_setnence, verbose=10):
        self.max_len_of_sentence = 80
        self.max_num_of_setnence = 1
        self.verbose = verbose

        self.num_of_char = 0
        self.num_of_label = 0
        self.unknown_label = ''

    def build_char_dictionary(self, char_dict=None, unknown_label='UNK'):
        """
            Define possbile char set. Using "UNK" if character does not exist in this set
        """

        if char_dict is None:
            char_dict = self.CHAR_DICT

        self.unknown_label = unknown_label

        chars = []

        for c in char_dict:
            chars.append(c)

        chars = list(set(chars))

        chars.insert(0, unknown_label)

        self.num_of_char = len(chars)
        self.char_indices = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(chars))
        self.indices_char = dict((i, c) for i, c in enumerate(chars))

        if self.verbose > 5:
            print('Totoal number of chars:', self.num_of_char)

            print('First 3 char_indices sample:', {k: self.char_indices[k] for k in list(self.char_indices)[:3]})
            print('First 3 indices_char sample:', {k: self.indices_char[k] for k in list(self.indices_char)[:3]})

        return self.char_indices, self.indices_char, self.num_of_char

    def convert_labels(self, labels):
        """
            Convert label to numeric
        """
        self.label2indexes = dict((l, i) for i, l in enumerate(labels))
        self.index2labels = dict((i, l) for i, l in enumerate(labels))

        if self.verbose > 5:
            print('Label to Index: ', self.label2indexes)
            print('Index to Label: ', self.index2labels)

        self.num_of_label = len(self.label2indexes)

        return self.label2indexes, self.index2labels

    def _transform_raw_data(self, df, x_col, y_col, label2indexes=None, sample_size=None):
        """
            ##### Transform raw data to list
        """

        x = []
        y = []

        actual_max_sentence = 0

        if sample_size is None:
            sample_size = len(df)

        for i, row in df.head(sample_size).iterrows():
            x_data = row[x_col]
            y_data = row[y_col]
            print(x_data)
            print(y_data)
            sentences = sent_tokenize(x_data)
            x.append(sentences)

            if len(sentences) > actual_max_sentence:
                actual_max_sentence = len(sentences)
            y.append(label2indexes[y_data])

        if self.verbose > 5:
            print('Number of news: %d' % (len(x)))
            print('Actual max sentence: %d' % actual_max_sentence)

        return x, y

    def _transform_training_data(self, x_raw, y_raw, max_len_of_sentence=None, max_num_of_setnence=None):
        """
            ##### Transform preorcessed data to numpy
        """
        unknown_value = self.char_indices[self.unknown_label]

        x = np.ones((len(x_raw), max_num_of_setnence, max_len_of_sentence), dtype=np.int64) * unknown_value
        y = np.array(y_raw)

        if max_len_of_sentence is None:
            max_len_of_sentence = self.max_len_of_sentence
        if max_num_of_setnence is None:
            max_num_of_setnence = self.max_num_of_setnence

        for i, doc in enumerate(x_raw):
            for j, sentence in enumerate(doc):
                if j < max_num_of_setnence:
                    for t, char in enumerate(sentence[-max_len_of_sentence:]):
                        if char not in self.char_indices:
                            x[i, j, (max_len_of_sentence - 1 - t)] = self.char_indices['UNK']
                        else:
                            x[i, j, (max_len_of_sentence - 1 - t)] = self.char_indices[char]

        return x, y

    def _build_character_block(self, block, dropout=0.3, filters=[64, 100], kernel_size=[3, 3],
                               pool_size=[2, 2], padding='valid', activation='relu',
                               kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'):

        for i in range(len(filters)):
            block = Conv1D(
                filters=filters[i], kernel_size=kernel_size[i],
                padding=padding, activation=activation, kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer)(block)


        block = Dropout(dropout)(block)
        block = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size[i])(block)

        block = GlobalMaxPool1D()(block)
        block = Dense(128, activation='relu')(block)
        return block

    def _build_sentence_block(self, max_len_of_sentence, max_num_of_setnence,
                              char_dimension=16,
                              filters=[[3, 5, 7], [200, 300, 300], [300, 400, 400]],
                              kernel_sizes=[[4, 3, 3], [5, 3, 3], [6, 3, 3]],
                              pool_sizes=[[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]],
                              dropout=0.4):

        sent_input = Input(shape=(max_len_of_sentence,), dtype='int64')
        embedded = Embedding(self.num_of_char, char_dimension, input_length=max_len_of_sentence)(sent_input)

        blocks = []
        for i, filter_layers in enumerate(filters):
            blocks.append(
                self._build_character_block(
                    block=embedded, filters=filters[i], kernel_size=kernel_sizes[i], pool_size=pool_sizes[i])
            )

        sent_output = concatenate(blocks, axis=-1)
        sent_output = Dropout(dropout)(sent_output)
        sent_encoder = Model(inputs=sent_input, outputs=sent_output)

        return sent_encoder

    def _build_document_block(self, sent_encoder, max_len_of_sentence, max_num_of_setnence,
                              num_of_label, dropout=0.3,
                              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy']):
        doc_input = Input(shape=(max_num_of_setnence, max_len_of_sentence), dtype='int64')
        doc_output = TimeDistributed(sent_encoder)(doc_input)

        doc_output = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=False, dropout=dropout))(doc_output)

        doc_output = Dropout(dropout)(doc_output)
        doc_output = Dense(128, activation='relu')(doc_output)
        doc_output = Dropout(dropout)(doc_output)
        doc_output = Dense(num_of_label, activation='sigmoid')(doc_output)

        doc_encoder = Model(inputs=doc_input, outputs=doc_output)
        doc_encoder.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=metrics)
        print(sent_encoder)
        return doc_encoder

    def preprocess(self, labels, char_dict=None, unknown_label='UNK'):
        if self.verbose > 3:
            print('-----> Stage: preprocess')

        self.build_char_dictionary(char_dict, unknown_label)
        self.convert_labels(labels)

    def process(self, df, x_col, y_col,
                max_len_of_sentence=None, max_num_of_setnence=None, label2indexes=None, sample_size=None):
        if self.verbose > 3:
            print('-----> Stage: process')

        if sample_size is None:
            sample_size = 1000
        if label2indexes is None:
            if self.label2indexes is None:
                raise Exception('Does not initalize label2indexes. Please invoke preprocess step first')
            label2indexes = self.label2indexes
        if max_len_of_sentence is None:
            max_len_of_sentence = self.max_len_of_sentence
        if max_num_of_setnence is None:
            max_num_of_setnence = self.max_num_of_setnence

        x_preprocess, y_preprocess = self._transform_raw_data(
            df=df, x_col=x_col, y_col=y_col, label2indexes=label2indexes)

        x_preprocess, y_preprocess = self._transform_training_data(
            x_raw=x_preprocess, y_raw=y_preprocess,
            max_len_of_sentence=max_len_of_sentence, max_num_of_setnence=max_num_of_setnence)

        if self.verbose > 5:
            print('Shape: ', x_preprocess.shape, y_preprocess.shape)

        return x_preprocess, y_preprocess

    def build_model(self, char_dimension=16, display_summary=False, display_architecture=False,
                    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy']):
        if self.verbose > 3:
            print('-----> Stage: build model')

        sent_encoder = self._build_sentence_block(
            char_dimension=char_dimension,
            max_len_of_sentence=self.max_len_of_sentence, max_num_of_setnence=self.max_num_of_setnence)

        doc_encoder = self._build_document_block(
            sent_encoder=sent_encoder, num_of_label=self.num_of_label,
            max_len_of_sentence=self.max_len_of_sentence, max_num_of_setnence=self.max_num_of_setnence,
            loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=metrics)

        if display_architecture:
            print('Sentence Architecture')
            IPython.display.display(SVG(model_to_dot(sent_encoder).create(prog='dot', format='svg')))
            print()
            print('Document Architecture')
            IPython.display.display(SVG(model_to_dot(doc_encoder).create(prog='dot', format='svg')))

        if display_summary:
            print(doc_encoder.summary())

        self.model = {
            'sent_encoder': sent_encoder,
            'doc_encoder': doc_encoder
        }

        return doc_encoder

    def train(self, x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, batch_size=64, epochs=1, shuffle=True):
        if self.verbose > 3:
            print('-----> Stage: train model')

        self.get_model().fit(
            x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
            batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, shuffle=shuffle)

    #         return self.model['doc_encoder']

    def predict(self, x, return_prob=False):
        if self.verbose > 3:
            print('-----> Stage: predict')

        if return_prob:
            return self.get_model().predict(x_test)

        return self.get_model().predict(x_test).argmax(axis=-1)

    def get_model(self):
        return self.model['doc_encoder']


"""
    Maximum number of characters per sentence is 256.
    Maximum number of sentence is 5
"""

char_cnn = CharCNN(max_len_of_sentence=256, max_num_of_setnence=5)

"""
    First of all, we need to prepare meta information including character dictionary 
    and converting label from text to numeric (as keras support numeric input only).
"""
char_cnn.preprocess(labels=df['label'].unique())

"""
    We have to transform raw input training data and testing to numpy format for keras input
"""
x_train, y_train = char_cnn.process(
    df=train_df, x_col='raw command', y_col='label')
x_test, y_test = char_cnn.process(
    df=test_df, x_col='raw command', y_col='label')

char_cnn.build_model()
char_cnn.train(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, batch_size=2048, epochs=2)

model = char_cnn.get_model()
#model.save('char_cnn_model')

model.summary()

#tf.saved_model.save(model, save_path)
tensorflow.keras.models.save_model(model, save_path, overwrite=True, include_optimizer=True)
```

Model summary:

---

Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

=================================================================

input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 1, 80)]           0

---

time_distributed (TimeDistri (None, 1, 384)            1429441

---

bidirectional (Bidirectional (None, 256)               525312

---

dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0

---

dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 128)               32896

---

dropout_5 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0

---

dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 258

=================================================================
Total params: 1,987,907
Trainable params: 1,987,907
Non-trainable params: 0

---

I receive the warning:

WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, 80), dtype=int64) for input (None, 80), but it was re-called on a Tensor with incompatible shape (None, 1, 80).

And execution errors out with:

ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1d_6 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 1, 80, 16]

Very new to TF/Keras.  Any help is appreciated, I've been trying to get this to work for a couple days now.

Comment: The error is clearly telling you that the shape of the data you are giving your model does not match the shape of the training data, this has nothing to do with model saving.

Comment: Why does it run without the error when I don't save the model at the end?

Comment: Hard to say because you did not point out which lines produce the errors and warnings,.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what line it is, I've tried editing all the shape inputs but the extra 1 in the incoming vector shape comes regardless.

Comment: It errors out at line 343,   tf.saved_model.save(model, save_path) based on the stack trace.  Stack trace ends at tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\input_spec.py", line 177, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(x.shape.as_list()))